# SharePoint 2010 Web Part expose web service?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Is it possible for a SharePoint 2010 Web Part to expose a web service (WCF?)?

I want a Web Part to send emails if a certain condition is met. The web part should be hit every 15 mins via a call initiated from a custom in-house scheduler.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A web part is just a visual component. It can expose a web service. However, custom web services can be created and deployed to SharePoint where you can access data from a site (a list maybe) and add custom logic to send the email.

[Here's a good guide on how to deploy web services to SharePoint](http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/03/10/how-deploy-a-wcf-service-to-sharepoint-2010.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Most of the logic/database methods needed will already exist in the web part, so was trying to avoid duplicating that in a separate web service...

Comment: You can put your shared logic in a dll and deploy it to the gac if you are concerned with code duplication.

Comment: What would be the better option though 1) a custom web service deployed to sharepoint sharing a dll (in the gac) with the web part, or 2) a self contained web part hosting a wcf service?

Comment: I think I know what you mean now. You could create the two features in the same project, so they will be deployed in the same dll. Yes, that might be an easier solution.